# Use netstandard 2.0 middleware into ASP.NET 4.5.2 WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a library in *netstandard2.0* and I use it in an *netcoreapp2.0* web application.

In my library I just created a middleware I call in my *core2* app.

In my netcoreapp2.0 I created an extension method on IApplicationBuilder to call the middleware.

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseSeriLogLogicalProperties(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        return applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<LogicalPropertiesLoggingMiddleware>();
    }
```

Then in my sample projet (core) I just call this extension method in my startup.cs in the Configure() section.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        app.UseSeriLogLogicalProperties();
    }
```

Now I'd like to call this middleware in another sample, this time in *net452*.

How could I do that?

Comment: The older Web API library is not compatible with the newer ASP.NET Core middleware I think.

Comment: Without cross targeting? You can't. `netstandard2.0` requires a minimum of .NET Framework 4.6.1. Plus what juunas said :P You may want to target OWIN instead of you want it work on both (assuming your libraries doesn't use anything from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` or `System.Web.*` namespaces): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @Tseng does my answer a better solution than using OWIN ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.
You can use PreApplicationStartMethod in AssemblyInfo.cs of your project, then you can subscribe BeginRequest.

So for each request of your application, you will pass in the method so you can do what you want.

First Create a class that will be called for every request

```
public class YourModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += Application_BeginRequest;
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = (HttpApplication)source;
        var context = application.Context;
        //your code
    }
}
```

Then create another class will be call in AssemblyInfo.cs that call the class above

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public static class PreApplicationStartCode
{
    private static bool startWasCalled;

    public static void Start()
    {
        if (startWasCalled)
        {
            return;
        }

        startWasCalled = true;

        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(YourModule));
    }
}
```

Then in AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PreApplicationStartCode), "Start")]
```

So when you'll call an action from a controller, you will pass everytime in YourModule.Application_BeginRequest() method, like a middleware in core apps.

Tested in a net452 WebApi.